# Blinking components of items list while dragging in FF

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I create a list of components (simple labels) and put a D&D mechanism on them (inspired by:  [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp](https://%20https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp)).
When I drag one component with a non smoothy movement, all components below in the list blink. Why?

**It seems important to say that this does appear in FF (recent version), not, for example, in Chromium.**

Codepen version: https://codepen.io/YACodepen/pen/xxByOrj.

Code of React part:

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const labels = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
    for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      manageMouse(labels[i]);
    }
  });

  const manageMouse = (label) => {
    // Inspired by: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp
    let pos1 = 0;
    let pos2 = 0;
    let pos3 = 0;
    let pos4 = 0;
    const initEvent = (e) => {
      if (e.button === 0) initDrag(e);
      else return;
    };

    function initDrag(e) {
      //label.style.zIndex = "1000";
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      document.onmouseup = closeDrag;
      document.onmousemove = performDrag;
    }

    const performDrag = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      pos1 = e.clientX - pos3;
      pos2 = e.clientY - pos4;
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      label.style.top = label.offsetTop + pos2 + "px";
      label.style.left = label.offsetLeft + pos1 + "px";
    };

    const closeDrag = () => {
      document.onmouseup = null;
      document.onmousemove = null;
      //label.style.zIndex = "auto";
    };

    label.onmousedown = initEvent;
  };

  const Label = ({ name, x, y }) => {
    return (
      <label
        className="label"
        id={name}
        style={{
          left: x,
          top: y
        }}
      >
        {name}
      </label>
    );
  };

  const names = ["1 Acturus", "2 Lyre", "3 Vega", "4 Deneb", "5 Altair"];
  let xInit = 20;
  let yInit = 60;
  let labels = [];
  for (let i in names) {
    labels.push(<Label name={names[i]} x={xInit} y={yInit} />);
    xInit = xInit + 20;
    yInit = yInit + 30;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        When dragging non smoothly, too bluntly, items of id below blink in FF
      </p>
      {labels}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if we're thinking about the same thing, but I assume you're talking about text selection while dragging elements, hence the *flickering / blinking*... I checked on FF and that was only thing which I noticed.

You can fix that issue by preventing text selection during draging:

```
function initDrag(e) {
    if (e.button !== 0) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDrag;
    document.onmousemove = performDrag;
  }
```

Since FF is based on a different engine, which may cause differences in rendering, it is also worth adding `requestAnimationFrame`, to improve framerate:

```
const performDrag = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    pos1 = e.clientX - pos3;
    pos2 = e.clientY - pos4;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      label.style.top = label.offsetTop + pos2 + "px";
      label.style.left = label.offsetLeft + pos1 + "px";
    });
  };
```

After that, I did not notice any anomalies.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why the e.preventDefault() disappeared! It was in the original code and I lost it during different tries... It solved my issue. As regards to requestAnimationFrame, I haven't seen any problem of animation and fluidity, so for the moment I keep it aside. But I'll try to remember if things deteriorate.